# Use traceparent header to set traceId and spanId in Micrometer

Tags: java, spring, logging, micrometer

I'm trying to send the `traceparent` header from the frontend to backend using Micrometer in Spring framework.

For example, I send the `traceparent` header into the frontend request:

```
traceparent=00-4bf92f3577b34da6a3ce929d0e0e4736-00f067aa0ba902b7-00
```

this is a log printed by the backend:

```
2023-08-08T09:56:32.338+02:00  INFO [KYC-BE,4bf92f3577b34da6a3ce929d0e0e4736,3cc2a015c655ce84]: test
```

The `traceId` is correctly read from the frontend request, instead the `spanId` is new, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not tell us what framework you use to create the HTTP endpoint but it is likely that a new span is created that's `parentId` is the `spanId` you send in the request header. This is normal behavior, otherwise you would not be able to distinguish between service boundaries.

Comment: I've indicated which framework I'm using only in tags. But, you're right, it isn't visible enough, I've updated the question.
Ok, I understand, a new spanId is created automatically and it isn't normal that the same spanId will be reused by the next application. Thanks

Comment: Oops, sorry, I did not see that. Thanks for adding it to the question.
Here's is a talk I gave earlier this year where you can see an example trace between 3 apps and 2 DBs using Spring Boot and instrumented clients with all the spans that are created: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQHuFnKvk_U&t=1878s

Comment: @JonatanIvanov When the traceflag=00 in the traceparent, a new span is created in springboot 3.0 (with otel). 
Is that the expected behaviour? Is there a way to override the tracestate coming in as part of traceparent to manipulate the creation of a new span (or using the parentId)